# [Origami+Quartz Composer]Same animation as Elevate App

Tags: quartz-composer, origami

i'm new to Origami+Quartz Composer.
I'm trying to replicate the animation the same as Elevate App. here is the animation:

1. Initial State:
   [image]
2. Click Agility Button
   [image]
3. Here's the animation
   [image]

The task is to have 2 layer. When we click the button, the second layer shows with a growing, hexagon mask staring at lower left corner of the image. But i don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: @HarshVardhan not yet